# The best way to organize WPF projects

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend, organization

I've started recently to develop a new software in WPF, and I still don't know which is the best way to organize the application, to be more productive with Visual Studio and Expression Blend.

I noticed 2 annoying things I'd like to solve:

1. I'm using Code Contracts in my projects, and when I run my project with Expression Blend, it launches the static analysis of the code. How can I stop that?
2. Which configuration of the project does Blend use by default? I've tried to disable Code Contracts in a new configuration. It works in VS as the static analysis is not launched, but it has no effects in Blend.

I've thinked about splitting the Windows Application in 2 parts: the first one containing the views of the WPF (app.exe) and the second one being the core of the project, with the logic code (app.core.dll), and I would just open the former project in Blend.

Any thoughts about that?

Thanks in advance

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this guy for some answers: http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/01/58/